# How to get a post views count using 'WordPress popular posts' plugin

Tags: plugins, php, theme-development, themes, popular-posts

I am using '[WordPress popular posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/)' plugin, and I'm trying to **get post total views by ID** using:
`wpp_get_mostpopular()` function.

Is there anyway to achieve that? **or** is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wpp_get_mostpopular()` will give you the posts with the most views. What you want to achieve is to get the post view count by passing a post id (or using it within the loop on the single page).

There is a function which accepts post id as parameter:

`<?php
if ( function_exists('wpp_get_views') ) {
    echo wpp_get_views(get_the_ID());
}
?>`

You can also show views in a specific time range. Have a look at:

https://github.com/cabrerahector/wordpress-popular-posts/wiki/2.-Template-tags